# libclang on iOS

Tags: objective-c, static-libraries

I can't seem to find anything on including libclang in an iOS project to use with syntax highlighting. All I've seen around the web is how to compile it as a dylib, and iOS doesn't allow custom dylibs, so I need a static binary that I can include. Is there a different argument to pass make to make a static library targeted for ARM and the simulator?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The clang linker flags are included with [this makefile](https://github.com/loarabia/Clang-tutorial/blob/master/makefile), as Clang's lib stretches across a massive collection of classes.

Comment: Okay, but how do I get a static library? Should I just copy all of the source files into a static library Xcode project? What I need is a way to use libclang in an iOS app.